# Current Status of mixnets for voting

Tags: anonymity, voting, mixnets

I am currently doing some research on universally verifiable mixnets, but it seems to me that there are too few papers about them after 2006 or so and most of them come from the team of Douglas Winkstrom.
Is this correct?

Can anybody point me to current references about mixnets and their use in voting protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few for shuffles.
The papers below will be good pointers for recent results.

- [Stephanie Bayer and Jens Groth: Efficient Zero-Knowledge Argument for Correctness of a Shuffle. EUROCRYPT 2012.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-29011-4_17)
- [Melissa Chase and Markulf Kohlweiss and Anna Lysyanskaya and Sarah Meiklejohn: Verifiable Elections That Scale for Free. PKC 2013.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-36362-7_29)
- [Melissa Chase and Markulf Kohlweiss and Anna Lysyanskaya and Sarah Meiklejohn: Succinct Malleable NIZKs and an Application to Compact Shuffles. TCC 2013.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-36594-2_6)

Answer (score 1):

By this point, mixnets are pretty mature technology.  The main reason you aren't finding many recent papers is they just work.  Instead, most of the research effort has been devoted to building larger systems (sometimes using mixnet as just one of many building blocks).